# How to convert pressure into wind speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure

I need to convert pressure into wind speed

My pressure value is 1590 Pascal.

I need the answer in meter/sec.

Comment: Why is the question tagged under special relativity? The question has nothing to do with special relativity.

Answer (score 2):

Pressure and velocity are different quantities, so it is not possible to simply convert them to each other without further information.

I assume you want to calculate the wind speed based on the measurement of the dynamic pressure. The latter is practically the pressure in a flow at a hyperbolic-fix point (where the velocity equals zero) minus the static pressure. So I would write Bernoulli's equation between a far field point and the fix-point:

$\frac{p_0}{\rho}+\frac{v_0^2}{2}=\frac{p_{fp}}{\rho}+\frac{v_{fp}^2}{2}$.

It is now assumed that the elevation of the two points are the same. Now, considering that $p_0=0$, the far-field velocity is

$v_0=\sqrt{\frac{2p_{fp}}{\rho}}=51.48\frac{m}{s}$,

which does not seem to be a kind weather for playing ping-pong outdoors.